# 'Invalid value' when setting default value in HTML5 datetime-local input

Tags: html, google-chrome

Can someone explain why when I set the default value of a datetime-local input with seconds other than :00, the browser gives me an error of "Invalid value."?

This may be a bug in Chrome's implementation of datetime-local since this bug does not appear in the latest Firefox and Safari.

**Error in Chrome: 30.0.1599.69**

[image]

**Chrome Canary: 32.0.1665.2 canary**

[image]

**This works:**

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="pub_date" value="2013-10-09T15:38:00">
```

**But this does not:**

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="pub_date" value="2013-10-09T15:38:15">
```

[Link to fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YNdee/1/)

Per the [W3 Spec for the datetime-local input element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html), the value attribute should contain "A string representing a local date and time."

```
Example:
1985-04-12T23:20:50.52
1996-12-19T16:39:57
```

I tried both of the above examples and they don't work either.

**Update: Confirmed Bug & Solution**

This behavior is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257369&q=datetime-local&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

As of today, the quick fix is to add the step attribute like so for non-zero seconds:

```
<input type="datetime-local" 
       name="pub_date" 
       value="2013-10-09T15:38:15" 
       step="1">
```

Comment: This bug has been fixed long ago enough that it is no longer an issue.

Comment: Seems like this bug still occurs on Safari. The step attribute workaround works though.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue still happens. It just was reported as a bug by a client on Safari 16.3, and I confirmed it on my dev build too. The step workaround still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="pub_date" value="2013-10-09T15:38:15" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome browser require date in **"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS"** format. So when we assign Date and Time, we need to assign it in required format otherwise it won't show the Date Time. Even we can confirm from browser inspector tool [Ctrl+I] in console tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is looking for a complete Time Stamp there is really no way around putting one.  Just zero out your milliseconds and you should be good.

Comment: This is maybe a workaround, but not really an answer to the question. The question was ` Can someone explain why when I set the default value of a datetime-local input with milliseconds other than :00, the browser gives me an error of "Invalid value."? `